# Prevent jumping to the top when exiting fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I add to this code the functionality of not jumping to the top of the page when exiting fullscreen mode? Many thanks

```
$('#toggle_fullscreen').on('click', function(){
  if (
    document.fullscreenElement ||
    document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
    document.mozFullScreenElement ||
    document.msFullscreenElement
  ) {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  } else {
    element = $('#fullscreen-wrapper').get(0);
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Exiting fullscreen shouldn't cause the page to jump to the top of the page. It might be something else causing that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not sure what else could be interfering. I have a separate function that removes the hashtag from the URL when clicking on the empty anchor tag

Comment: "*I have a separate function that removes the hashtag from the URL*" - are you, by some chance, **reloading the page**?

Comment: "*clicking on the empty anchor tag*" - neither of these sound like your issue is related to exiting fullscreen mode.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

When switching to full screen, save the current scroll position in a variable.
And when exiting, just scroll the window to that position

```js
let lastScrollPosition;

$('#toggle_fullscreen').on('click', function(){
  if (
    document.fullscreenElement ||
    document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
    document.mozFullScreenElement ||
    document.msFullscreenElement
  ) {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollPosition);
  } else {
    element = $('#fullscreen-wrapper').get(0);
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    lastScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working for me unfortunately

Comment: I supposed that it’s the window that should scroll. I haven’t seen your code. It might be a div or something. That should be replaced with window in the code

Comment: I've only been able to get this sort of thing to work by using a `setTimeout()` rather than attempting to scroll immediately, but the delay required depends on browser performance, so it's all very hacky.